# Hide and remove class on blur

Tags: jquery

See this:
http://jsfiddle.net/AFhvS/4/

Try remove the text inside the input field in one of the two filled fields: http://jsfiddle.net/AFhvS/5/ and then go on blur, it should appear a alert, but it doesnt, so i have done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may add the class you want to remove

```
$('.upstartRemoveClass').removeClass("upstartRemoveClass");
```

You may also want to look into when you tab between items, at the moment you are using the click event on the tr, maybe you want to use the `focus` event on your inputs instead?

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/AFhvS/7/ changed events on when things should trigger.

Comment: Try remove the text inside the input field in one of the two filled fields: http://jsfiddle.net/AFhvS/5/ and then go on blur, it should appear a alert, but it doesnt, so i have done something wrong??

Comment: Im not 100% what you want to do but this is me guessing: http://jsfiddle.net/AFhvS/7/

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, or at least lead you in the right direction:

```
$('tr').removeClass('upstartRemoveClass');
```

or in your blur function:

```
$(this).removeClass('upstartRemoveClass');
```

Comment: Try remove the text inside the input field in one of the two filled fields: http://jsfiddle.net/AFhvS/5/ and then go on blur, it should appear a alert, but it doesnt, so i have done something wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You've put the `onBlur` handler on the `tr` instead of on the `input`. That's why it's not firing.